# Flutter One Signal Not Pushing Notification in real devices

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, notifications

i am pushing notification with one signal and external user id.It works in emulators but in real devices, according to console it return `Prompted But Never Answered` error. It says Remove any other notification SDK or prompting code. It is probably about `firebase FCM` but i can't find a way to remove prompting code.

Here is my pubspec.yaml dependicies

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.4.0  
  easy_localization: ^3.0.2
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  flutter_slidable: ^3.0.0
  ticket_widget: ^0.0.1
  qr_flutter: ^4.1.0
  flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.5
  grouped_list: ^5.1.2
  appinio_swiper: ^2.0.1
  table_calendar: ^3.0.9
  flutter_rating_stars: ^1.0.3+4
  google_fonts: ^4.0.3
  glassmorphism: ^3.0.0
  sprung: ^3.0.1
  image_picker: ^1.0.1 
  url_launcher: ^6.1.11
  dio: ^5.3.2
  flutter_session_manager: ^1.0.3
  convert: ^3.1.1
  map_launcher: ^2.5.0+1 
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.7.2+3
  mobile_scanner: ^3.4.1
  firebase_core: ^2.14.0
  google_sign_in: ^6.1.4
  sign_in_with_apple: ^5.0.0 
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  onesignal_flutter: ^5.0.0
  random_string_generator: ^2.0.0 
  flutter_holo_date_picker: ^1.1.0
  map_location_picker: ^1.2.1
  provider: ^6.0.5
  image_network: ^2.5.4+1
```

and here is my one signal setup

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
  OneSignal.Debug.getDeviceState().then((value) {});
  OneSignal.Notifications.requestPermission(true);
  try {
    OneSignal.Debug.setLogLevel(OSLogLevel.verbose);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    OneSignal.initialize(androidKey);
  } else {
    OneSignal.initialize(iosKey);
  }
```

There is a crush message in android which says

```
Found constructor: public com.onesignal.core.internal.operations.impl.OperationRepo(java.util.List,com.onesignal.core.internal.operations.impl.OperationModelStore,com.onesignal.core.internal.config.ConfigModelStore,com.onesignal.core.internal.time.ITime)
```

the way i push notification is

```
 try {
    var url = Uri.parse("https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    var client = http.Client();
    var headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "Authorization": "Basic $auth",
    };

    var body = {
      "app_id": iosId,
      "contents": {"en": message},//if its "tr" it doesnt work
      "include_external_user_ids": [externalUserId],
      "android_sound": "sahwah",
      "ios_sound": "sahwah.wav",
      "priority": "HIGH"
    };
    var response =
        await client.post(url, headers: headers, body: json.encode(body));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("Notification sent successfully to $externalUserId");
    } else {
      print("Error sending notification: ${response}");
    }
    print("gönder 1");
  } catch (e) {
```

Comment: Apart from one signal are you using any other library like firebase or local notifications library?

Comment: No I don't use any of them but there is a Messaging tab in the firebase project. But i am not using to send notification. Am i have to remove that?

Comment: and when i try to push notification on one signal server the app is crashing and closing

Comment: Please add your pubspec.yaml depedencies list

Comment: Hi! I edited as you want can you check again

Comment: Maybe i can have trouble with onesignal sdk setup. Do you have any tutarial for new version

Comment: can you please add complete console error message and its complete stack trace that you're encountering when receiving notifications on your device.

Comment: Also add your onesignal implementation code

Comment: I edited as you wish. But there is no error message apearing when i didn't get notification. In OneSignal console there is an error which says "apn delegate never fired"

Comment: Have you add dependency in android/IOS code for native notification permission and handling as per one signal?

Comment: i didn't add handling. It is weird that some of emulators recieving notifications and some of them are not. I am editing Question with my send notification details. In simulator which recieving notification i am changing content type 'en' to 'tr' it is not recieving anymore. If you can see something can you explain to me.

Comment: i implemented notification listener. One of my emulators didn't get notifications and listener can't hear anything.

Comment: Please go through this setup document - https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/how-to-prompt-for-push-permissions-with-an-in-app-message.  Are you receiving the notification Prompt dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create new app in OneSignal and initilize that app. It worked.